# Emacs letter-flickering

Tags: emacs

I have a letter-flickering problem which I can't track down.

The main issue is that I can't deliberately start the bug, but when it occurs, it continues to flicker around the cursor. I have made a small screencast that illustrate the issue:

[image: screencast]

It occurs in

- In any major-mode
- In the mini-buffer
- Completion buffers

When I try to bisect some of the elisp-configuration I can still reproduce it; it is just harder than before (=longer time).

Do you have any clue on how I should track the bug down?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: yes, but I am not sure that it is natively emacs fault.

Comment: Which platform and version of Emacs? Compiled by hand or installed via a package manager? Try with a completely blank init file and add your configuration progressively.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Emacs version!

Comment: Okay, now it is jumping again. It is really weird.

Comment: If you still intend to debug this yourself, `etc/DEBUG` has sections `Debugging Emacs Redisplay problems` and `Debugging incorrect screen updating`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. However, I found out that it was due to some misbehaviour in the background timers. If I reset the timer-list variable it stopped flickering.